# How to add exception handling to an existing Rake task?

Tags: ruby, rake, rake-task

I want to rescue an exception thrown by a rake task provided by an external gem.

Ideally, I would like to create a rake task with the same name that invokes the original one and just handles the exception. Something like:

```
original_task = Rake.application.tasks.find { |t| t.name == "original_namespace:original_task" }
Rake::Task["original_namespace:original_task"].clear

namespace :original_namespace do
  task original_task: :environment do
    begin
      original_task.invoke
    rescue SystemExit
      # do something
    end
  end
end
```

This doesn't work because it seems that you can't just copy a rake task and hold it in memory.

Answer (score 3):

This would be an overkill, but it should work:

```
Rake::Task.prepend(Module.new do
  def invoke(*args)
    case name
    when "original_namespace:original_task"
      begin
        super(*args)
      rescue => e
        Logger.warn("Task failed, rescued")
      end
    else super(*args)
    end
  end
end)
```

Once added somewhere in the initializer, it should make it rescuing the respective exception automagically.

Comment: Sorry but it didn't work. This code (saved in initializers) does not even get executed.

Comment: Then discover what is being definitely loaded during task initialization and put the code there. I have a little clue about Rails.

Comment: You can put it in the Rakefile.